# async.each does not finish without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a simple function to where I get the word count from an url. The script works if I have a low amount of urls. I only limit async 4 at a time. I watch my ram and cpu and it doesn't go near the max on my machine. Let's say after about 70ish urls there is no error. The script just sets there. I have it in a try catch block and it never catches. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried lodash forEach instead of async and I get the same issue.

```
const async = require('async')
const wordcount = require('wordcount')
const afterLoad = require('after-load')
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text')

function getWordCount(urls, cb) {
    async.eachLimit(urls, 4, function(url, cbe) {
           try {
                let html = afterLoad(url) // https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-load
                let text = htmlToText.fromString(html)
                let urlWordCount = wordcount(text) // https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordcount
                console.log(url, urlWordCount)
                cbe(null)
           } catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
                urlWordCount = 0
                console.log(url, urlWordCount, err)
                cbe(null)
           }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("finished getting wordcount", err)
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            cb(null)
        }
    })
}

getWordCount(["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit"], function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: At a glance what are `afterLoad()` and `wordCount()` actually doing? There are no "obvious" async calls within the loop, which would mean you actually don't need the `eachLimit()` unless those function are actually async. And if they are, then you're doing it wrong because you won't be able to return values from them like that. The URL list makes me suspect they actually are doing something like a "remote request" which is indeed async. That's the code which is the problem here. Also what version of NodeJS are you using? Since you likely don't need the library at all.

Comment: Also `cbe(err)` to return the error if any. But if those functions are actually working "synchronous", then a stardard `for` loop will do here. The point of the `eachLimit()` is to fire the callback to "iterate" only when "internal async calls" have actually completed.

Comment: by the way  - `after-load` does have an asynchronous implementation - though, you're not using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the synchronous implementation of that `after-load` module, but it's indeed hard to judge unless you get an actual error (you could put some console.logs here and there on every line and see where your code actually gets stuck - or use a debugger for the same purpose).

What I'd propose though is to use proper asynchronous code - I run the example below with a set of 1000 urls and it did not get stuck - with usage of [scramjet] it's also more readable:

```
const {StringStream} = require('scramjet');
const wordcount = require('wordcount');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text');
const {promisify} = require('util');

StringStream.fromArray(["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit"])
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 4})
    .parse(async url => ({
        url,
        response: await fetch(url)
    }))
    .map(async ({url, response}) => {
        const html = await response.text();
        const text = htmlToText.fromString();
        const count = wordcount(text);

        return {
            url,
            count
        };
    })
    .each(console.log)
;
```

I actually run this from a file with the URL's by changing the first lines to:

```
StringStream.from(fs.createReadStream('./urls-list.txt'), 'utf-8')
    .lines()
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 4})
    // and so on.
```